# SDL: Unable to flip multiple surfaces

Tags: c, sdl, graphics2d

I've been trying to flip surfaces and have been successful if I'm only flipping a single surface (the same surface I got back from `SDL_SetVideoMode`). If I try to flip the surface I get back from `SDL_DisplayFormat`, nothing happens. I've attached demo code that demonstrates my problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

void main()
{
    int i;
    SDL_Surface *mysurface1;
    SDL_Surface *mysurface2;
    char *pxl;

    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    mysurface1 = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 8, SDL_DOUBLEBUF|SDL_HWSURFACE );

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
            pxl = (char *)mysurface1->pixels + i*mysurface1->pitch + i;
            *pxl = 100; // Red Line
    }

    SDL_Flip(mysurface1); // Works, we see a red line

    sleep(5);
    printf("Sleeping for 5...\n");

    mysurface2 = SDL_DisplayFormat(mysurface1);

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
            pxl = (char *)mysurface2->pixels + i*mysurface2->pitch + i;
            *pxl = 255; // White line
    }

    SDL_Flip(mysurface2); // White line doesnt appear

    printf("Done... No white line\n");

    sleep(10);
}
```

Has anyone ever seen this before? Again, I think I tracked it down to surfaces that wont display if its a surface I got back from `SDL_DisplayFormat`. If I do it on the surface I get back from `SDL_SetVideoMode`, then I see the red line and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can only flip the main display surface (the one created with `SDL_SetVideoMode`). In order to make your other surface visible, you need to blit it onto the main surface. Lookup `SDL_BlitSurface` for details on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the screen to the `SDL_Flip` function. The flip function modifies the value of `screen->pixels` so that it points to the surface that isn't visible on the screen.

However, this is only applicable to video devices such as SVGA and DGA. On X11, calling `SDL_Flip(screen)` is equivalent to calling `SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"

void main()
{
    int i;
    SDL_Surface *screen;
    char *pxl;

    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 8, SDL_DOUBLEBUF|SDL_HWSURFACE );

    printf("Drawing the red line ...\n");
    printf("screen->pixels = %p\n", screen->pixels);
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pxl = (char *)screen->pixels + i*screen->pitch + i;
        *pxl = 100; // Red Line
    }

    printf("Flip screens\n");
    SDL_Flip(screen); // Display the red line

    printf("Drawing the white line ...\n");
    printf("screen->pixels = %p\n", screen->pixels);
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pxl = (char *)screen->pixels + i*screen->pitch + i;
        *pxl = 255; // White line
    }

    sleep(3);
    printf("Flip screens\n");
    SDL_Flip(screen); // Display the white line

    sleep(10);
}
```

On my Linux notebook, this prints:

```
Drawing the red line ...
screen->pixels = 0xb6c8c008
Flip screens
Drawing the white line ...
screen->pixels = 0xb6c8c008
Flip screens
```

The value of `screen->pixels` is the same, but this is only because on X11 the flip operation is a no-operation. On a video device such as SVGA or DGA, the two values would be different.

Answer (score 0):

First, it seems `SDL_Flip()` only works on surfaces that correspond to the screen or a window, like those created by `SDL_SetVideoMode()`.  Your other surface is off-screen; it doesn't make much sense to double-buffer it (or flip it), and it most likely isn't double-buffered anyway.  Being an off screen surface, it won't appear until you blit it to your display surface with `SDL_BlitSurface()` or a similar function -- then, the changes will be visible next time you flip the display surface.

Essentially, `mysurface2` isn't actually on your display until you put it there, by blitting it onto a surface that *is* on your display.  If you replace the following:

```
SDL_Flip(mysurface2); // White line doesnt appear
```

With this:

```
SDL_BlitSurface(mysurface2,NULL,mysurface1,NULL);
SDL_Flip(mysurface1);
```

...then your code will probably work as you expect.